# Parse attribute value from HTML

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I want to get data from webpage:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
    name="vlc" ratio="16:9" 
    autoplay="yes" loop="no" 
    rtsp-caching="3000" volume="100" 
    width="670" height="380" 
    target="http://185.2.42.106/stream/?d=1402956552&token=5119675517383">
```

I want to get the target attribute value. I searched whole internet and didn't found anything that I understood. Could someone show me the trick and explain it?

Ok, so I got it working with this code:

```
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = webGet.Load("http://www.spusti.net/play-vlc-185");
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//embed")[0];
        var val = node.Attributes["target"].Value; //10743
        MessageBox.Show(val);
```

Don't ask me how, but I did it. Thanks for your time CopyPaste!

Comment: Did you take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)? This should fit your needs.

Comment: So I searched a bit and found that Html Agility Pack doesn't support attribute selection - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/1720 Is this true?

Comment: If you're trying to parse data, please take a look at `XPath`. You can use `XPath` combine with `Html Agility Pack` to get everything you need. Maybe after reading about `XPath`, you will understand `DrCopyPaste`'s answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working for you; just one thing I want to point out: you're using `SelectNodes("//embed")`-method now wich essentially will give you all `embed`-nodes under root, then you just select the first one by attaching `[0]`, as soon as the structure of that target page changes that strategy will possibly not work anymore (i.e. if there was an additional `embed`-node inserted before the one already existing on that page, that strategy won't work anymore). Anyways have fun with your working code ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The page shouldn't change and it works right now, but it's good to know this in future. Again thanks for your time, have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that is discussed in [the link you commented on](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/1720) is that you work on nodes in this library, but not on attributes directly.
(You use [XPATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to point to what you want to select in that library, though XPATH itself supports the selection of attributes, HTML Agility Pack does not, it just supports selecting nodes)

That said, attributes being part of nodes, that should be no problem for you at all!
You can easily get attributes' values from nodes that you select in [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Since you asked for some more clarification in your comment, I hope I can clear up at least some of your troubles:

First Html Agility Pack works on nodes, that is what an html-tag (like `<embed>`) gets transformed into.

The value you want to get is an attribute on that node, so you need to select that node first.

To be able to select the node you need to identify that, the easiest way (if you have control over the html source) to do that is to just assign an id to it *(like `<embed id='someId' someAttribute='someValue' />`)*.

Now you're almost done, now you just need the xpath-expression to tell the parser where to look for your node, if you cannot assign an id to that node you will have to try to find it by document structure *(for example: the embed-node inside the div-node inside body, but then you could get a collection of nodes, not just a single one, then you will need to use `SelectNodes()` and iterate over them and decide in each iteration if you got the right one)*

### TLDR;

Following is an example setting up a simple html with two nodes of the same tag-type having different ids the code selects just one of them and outputs the attribute-value of `someAttribute` *(note in your production code you should check for the existence of that attribute before using it ;))*:

```
// to run this start a new console project in visual studio
// and paste this code into main method of program.cs
// open nuget package console and type "Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack"
// and hit enter
// add a "using HtmlAgilityPack;"
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
string someStupidHtml = @"
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jusATest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed id='someId' someAttribute='someValue' />
        <embed id='anotherId' someAttribute='anotherValue' />
    </body>
</html>";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someStupidHtml);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
doc.Load(stream);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//embed[@id='anotherId']");

Console.WriteLine("its a node already with someAttribute={0}", node.Attributes["someAttribute"].Value);

Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I don't understand nearly anything from what you wrote. I'm really new to parsing, this library and things around that. If you have time, could you please explain everything? I tryed to Copy and Paste this to a new project and even then I got an error.

Comment: @user3890664 I tried to improve my post, but it looks like an awful wall of text now, however I hope I could clear up some of your concerns.

Comment: So after reading your answers multiple times, I still didn't understand few things, so I searched and searched and finally I got it working with the code that I "edited" to the answer. Don't ask me how I did it, but I did it. :D Thanks you for your time CopyPaste!